# jQueryui sortable: How to get the ID of the li-element another li-element was sorted onto?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have this and guess that this list is a sortable one:

```
<ul>
   <li id="a">Hey</li>
   <li id="b">Ho</li>
   <li id="c">Silver</li>
   <li id="d">!</li>
</ul>
```

Now I'm sorting the list. I move the third `<li id="c">Silver</li>` on before the first `<li id="a">Hey</li>` what makes the list looks like this:

```
<ul>
  <li id="c">Silver</li>
  <li id="a">Hey</li>
  <li id="b">Ho</li>
  <li id="d">!</li>
</ul>
```

What I need to resolve now is the id of the DOM element ive sorted my list entry onto. In my example this should be "a" as it is the id of the first `<li>` I've sorted my third `<li>` onto.

Comment: What are you asking, when you say "on to" it makes it sound like you want the ID of the `<ul>`, do you mean you want the ID of the next element, if it exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the id of the dragged and dropped element; use that to get the id of the next element on the same level:

```
$('#id_of_the_dragged_element').next().attr('id')
```

Comment: Hey @saluce Do you know how i can get the element on the changed ID? i can't seem to find it out.